# Copying __m256d in constructor causes segfault

Tags: c++, g++, stdvector, intrinsics, avx

The code below is a simplified case that causes the error that I am seeing in my code. When I manually call the constructor for `A(const A&)` then everthing is fine, but when I try to copy one `vector<A>` to another, I get a segfault at the line `A(const A& in) : vec(in.vec) {}`.

Why does this happen, and how can I work my code around it?

EDIT: So I added the code by @mpromonet and it runs to completion now, BUT 1. it is much slower (a factor of more than 3x) and 2. when I compile with `-pg` to find out why, I get a segfault when calling `_mm256_add_pd`.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;


struct A {
    union {
        struct {
            double a, b, c;
        };
        __m256d vec;
    };

    A() : a(0), b(0), c(0) {}
    A(const A& in) : vec(in.vec) {}
};

int main() {
    vector<A> e(10);
    vector<A> b;
    b = e;
}
```

EDIT:
This code accounts for most of the time in my program. Compiled with `g++ --std=c++11 -ffast-math -march=native -O3 -fno-inline -g -pg`. See the call graph below. I have an array of `Electron` objects which contain two `Vector` objects declared with `__attribute__((aligned(32)))`. To make the array aligned I do

```
Electron* data_orig = new Electron[s+3]; 
Electron* data = (Electron*)((void*)data_orig + 64 - (size_t)data_orig % 64);
```

Without AVX

```
struct Vector {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    Vector(double a, double b, double c) :
        x(a), y(b), z(c)
        {}

    Vector(const Vector& u) :
        x(u.x), y(u.y), z(u.z)
        {}


    Vector(const UnitVector& u);


    Vector operator*=(const double m) { x*=m; y*=m; z*=m; return *this; }
    Vector operator+=(const Vector& in) {
        x+=in.x; y+=in.y; z+=in.z;
        return *this;
    }
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os) {
        os << "x:" << x << " y:" << y << " z:" << z;
        return os;
    }

};
Vector::Vector(const UnitVector& u) :
        x(u.x*u.mag), y(u.y*u.mag), z(u.z*u.mag)
        {}
```

With AVX

```
struct Vector {
    union {
        struct {
            double x;
            double y;
            double z;
        };
        __m256d vec __attribute__ ((aligned (32)));
    };

    Vector(double a, double b, double c) :
        x(a), y(b), z(c)
        {}

    Vector(const Vector& in) : vec(in.vec) {}
    //: x(in.x), y(in.y), z(in.z) {}


    Vector(const UnitVector& u);

    Vector operator*=(const double m) {
        vec = _mm256_mul_pd(vec, _mm256_set1_pd(m));
        return *this;
    }

    Vector operator+=(const Vector& in) {
        vec = _mm256_add_pd(vec, in.vec);
        return *this;
    }
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os) {
        os << "x:" << x << " y:" << y << " z:" << z;
        return os;
    }

};
Vector::Vector(const UnitVector& u) { vec = _mm256_mul_pd(u.vec, _mm256_set1_pd(u.mag));}
```

[image: Call Graph without AVX]

Comment: I think this is because of how vector deals with memory - there might be a pointer misalignment

Comment: The object is definitely misaligned. The *somewhat* scary part is that newer compilers sometimes issue misaligned accesses in all cases. So while it won't crash, you might take a performance hit. Worst of all, you won't even know it.

Comment: It looks like `__m256d` is just a typedef on `double` with `__attribute__((__vector_size__(32)))`

Comment: @Mysticial: if the memory is aligned, `vmovups` is just as fast as `vmovaps`; the only difference is that it doesn’t crash when the data isn’t aligned.  The only reason to use `vmovaps` is for hard enforcement of alignment.

Comment: @StephenCanon Yeah. It's that enforcement that I want. But the latest VS and ICC compilers always use `vmovups`. So I don't even know when something is misaligned. :(

Comment: @Mysticial: it’s safe to say that most users prefer “not crashing” =)  FWIW, there's a perf counter for misaligned loads, and you can always hard-check alignment yourself.

Comment: I've added some more info. I'm going to try replacing all occurrences of `vmovapd` with `vmovupd` in the assembly.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble is that your system’s allocator doesn’t guarantee 32B alignment, which your compiler is assuming for __m256d types.

It sounds like you’re targeting clang?  If so, do the following:

```
typedef double __attribute__((vector_size(32),aligned(16))) m256d_unaligned;
```

And then in your struct definition use this:

```
m256d_unaligned vec;
```

to tell the compiler not to assume that the vector is aligned.  (If you’re on a system that doesn’t guarantee even 16B alignment—unlikely-you may need to decrease the aligned argument further).

A more invasive (but possibly more performant) solution is to use a custom allocator that guarantees 32B alignment for types that require it.

Comment: Actually I am targeting g++ 4.8. Does that change anything?

Comment: I *believe*, but I’m not sure, that this will also work with recent GCCs.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Right now I'm just replacing `vmovapd` with `vmovupd` in the assembly and it is running; albeit slowly.

Comment: Unfortunately trying to align it that way didn't work, so I went ahead used arrays which I made sure to allocate 32 byte aligned. No errors now. It's extremely slow though, 13.5 seconds without AVX intrinsics and 71  seconds with. Any idea why?

Comment: I've added the parts of my code that take the longest to my question above rather than pasting the whole thing.